# Getting the Row index of a table on onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the row index of a table on keypress

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" onkeypress="test(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="test2(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="test2(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function test(x)
{
 alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
function test2(x) {
    alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
</script>
```

i am confused as test2 returns the row but test one shows undefined.
Any explanation as to why it returns undefined and the proper way to get the index would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I did modify my question as to what difficulty i am facing.. thanks @pugazh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert("Row index is: " + x.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
```

input´s parent is td and td´s parent is tr. you bind onkeypress to the input element. and onclick to the tr element

Comment: thank you!! but i like to know what is the difference, Sorry i am a newbie in javascript

Comment: input´s parent is td and td´s parent is tr.

you bind onkeypress to the input element.

and onclick to the tr element

Comment: @FrankWisniewski I think your comment would be a good addition to your answer since it provides the first part of the answer OP requested

Answer (score 2):

You should give a class name to the elements in your array in order to make it easier to locate them once you need to fetch them. Let's say you name your cells `table-cell` and your rows `table-row` :

```
$('#Items').on('click', '.table-cell', function(){
      $(this); // the clicked cell
      $(this).parent('.table-row); // the row in which the clicked cell is
});
```

Comment: that's what i was about to say, he should use classes or such to identify elements. side note: if an inline javascript sends `this` as an argument, you can make it a jQuery element by using `$(arg)` in the function, and use `.parent()` on it to get the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

The event is `onkeypress` for the textbox ,so when you pass `this` the script receives object of type `[HTMLInputElement]` whereas when you click the test2 since the event is invoked `onclick` the javascript receives x as `[HTMLTableRowElement]`

So the there will be no `rowIndex` property available for the textbox and for the script it remains undefined.